# How to delete a column using jquery by clicking on a cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that I add columns to it on the fly. Each column has an `[X]` icon on the top, when a user clicks on it, I need to delete the entire column.

I created a [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/FSdk2/526/) page to show you what I have done.

As you can see I have `[X]` icon on the top and when I click it, it is deleting the 3rd column in the table because I am specifying a fixed column i.e. 3. But I need to be able to remove the current column not the 3rd column.

How can I determine what is the current column and delete every `tr` with in the table matching the correct position?

Comment: Have you considered DataTables plugin? Will take a look at the fiddle.

Comment: I am not sure that DataTable is something I would want to use for this project. DataTable may be an over kill here.

Comment: Code in your question, you should know that by now. In fact I'm sure you saw the big, red warning message about linking to jsFiddle so you figured you'd sidestep that by highlighting `[X]` as code.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to `.empty()` instead of `.remove()`? It's a weird interaction as is

Comment: @Jaylen added an answer you might like.

Answer (score 2):

Could try something like this:

```
$('.removeMe').click(function() {
    var indexToRemove = $(this).index();
    $(".defaultTable tbody tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find("td:eq("+indexToRemove+")").remove();
     });
});
```

**Edit:**

Here's a fiddle which will remove them, the headers, and any dynamically-created columns as well. It uses jQuery's `.on()` method with delegated events so that even elements which are created dynamically will have this event listener added to them. `.click()` is a direct binding and will only bind it to elements which already exist so newly-created elements won't have the event listeners binded to them.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenelberger/dsL31yek/

Comment: To get rid of the loop you can use `$("tr").find("td:eq("+$(this).index()+"), th:eq("+$(this).index()+")").remove();`

Comment: It does not remove the column that are added on the fly

Comment: @Jaylen I added a fiddle which cleaned up the code a bit and also removes columns that are added on the fly. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/:

```
$('#testTable1').on('click', '.removeMe', function () {
   $(".defaultTable thead tr th:nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")").remove();
   $(".defaultTable tbody tr td:nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")").remove();
});
```

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.defaultTable').dragtable();

  $('#test1').click(function () {
    $("#testTable1 > thead > tr").each(function () {
      $(this).append('<th>New Column</th>');
    });

    $("#testTable1 > tbody > tr").each(function (i, e) {
      if (i == 0) {
        $(this).append('<td class="removeMe">[X]</td>');
      } else {
        $(this).append('<td>New cell in the column</td>');
      }
    });
    $('.defaultTable').removeData().dragtable();
  });

  $('#testTable1').on('click', '.removeMe', function () {
    $(".defaultTable thead tr th:nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")").remove();
    $(".defaultTable tbody tr td:nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")").remove();
  });

  $('.defaultTable').removeData().dragtable();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://akottr.github.io/css/akottr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://akottr.github.io/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//rawgithub.com/akottr/dragtable/master/dragtable.css" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/akottr/dragtable/master/jquery.dragtable.js"></script>

<!-- only for jquery.chili-2.2.js -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//akottr.github.io/js/jquery.chili-2.2.js"></script>


<div class="sample">

    <button type="button" id="test1">Add column</button>

    <div class="demo">
        <h4>demo</h4>

        <div class="demo-content">
            <table class="defaultTable sar-table" id="testTable1">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>TIME</th>
                    <th>%user</th>
                    <th>%nice</th>
                    <th>%system</th>
                    <th>%iowait</th>
                    <th>%idle</th>
                </tr>

                </thead>


                <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td class="removeMe">[X]</td>
                    <td class="removeMe">[X]</td>
                    <td class="removeMe">[X]</td>
                    <td class="removeMe">[X]</td>
                    <td class="removeMe">[X]</td>
                    <td class="removeMe">[X]</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>12:10:01 AM</td>
                    <td>28.86</td>
                    <td>0.04</td>
                    <td>1.65</td>
                    <td>0.08</td>
                    <td>69.36</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>12:20:01 AM</td>
                    <td>26.54</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>1.64</td>
                    <td>0.08</td>
                    <td>71.74</td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>12:30:01 AM</td>
                    <td>29.73</td>
                    <td>0.00</td>
                    <td>1.66</td>
                    <td>0.09</td>
                    <td>68.52</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Would advise switching to `$('.removeMe').on("click", function(){});` to allow it to work on dynamically created elements.

Comment: This also would not remove the `th` elements.

Comment: I updated the answer to add the correct libraries for your snipt to evaluate it. But is it not working as expected. if remove most of the column you get an error. + you can't remove a column that is added on the fly

Comment: @Jaylen Snippet updated. The problems were: I messed draggable and dragtable. For the event delegation it works fine. The problem was related on how the new columns were added: the [X] button is in the first row of the body. Try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
var index = $(this).index();

$(".defaultTable tr").each(function() {

     //remove body
     $(this).find("td:eq("+index+")").remove();

     //and head
     $(this).find("th:eq("+index+")").remove();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FSdk2/530/)

Comment: This does not remove the columns that were added on the fly

Answer (score 0):

You could try by getting column number from table

```
$('.removeMe').click(function(){
var colNum = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));// getting the column number
console.log(colNum);
$(".defaultTable tbody tr").each(function() {
$(this).find("td:eq("+colNum+")").remove();
});                         

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding mine in with the lot of answers:

Working Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/h0asbe6o/

**jQuery**

```
function removeColumn(n, o) {
  o = (o != "undefined") ? o : $("#testTable1");
  console.log("Removing Column '" + o.find("thead tr th:eq(" + n + ")").text() + "' (" + n + ") from " + o.attr("id"));
  o.find("tr").each(function(k, e) {
    $(e).find("th:eq(" + n + ")").empty().remove();
    $(e).find("td:eq(" + n + ")").empty().remove();
  });
  return true;
}
```

Also you'd want to fix a few creation issues:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.defaultTable').dragtable();

  $('#test1').click(function() {
    $("#testTable1 > thead > tr").append('<th>New Column</th>');

    $("#testTable1 > tbody > tr").each(function(key, el) {
      if (key == 0) {
        var rm = $("<span>", {
            class: "removeMe"
          })
          .html("[X]")
          .click(function() {
            removeColumn($(this).index());
            $(this).remove();
          });
        rm.appendTo(el);
      } else {
        $(el).append('<td>New cell in the column</td>');
      }
    });

    $('.defaultTable').removeData().dragtable();
  });

  $('.removeMe').on("click", function() {
    removeColumn($(this).index());
    $('.defaultTable').removeData().dragtable();
  });
});
```

This will create new columns properly and allow you to delete either static or dynamically created elements.

**EDIT**

If you felt like improving the UI, you could do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/h0asbe6o/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="sample">
  <button type="button" id="test1">Add column</button>
  <div class="demo">
    <h4>demo</h4>
    <div class="demo-content">
      <table class="defaultTable sar-table" id="testTable1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><span class="cTitle handle">TIME</span><span class="removeMe">[x]</span></th>
            <th><span class="cTitle handle">%user</span><span class="removeMe">[x]</span></th>
            <th><span class="cTitle handle">%nice</span><span class="removeMe">[x]</span></th>
            <th><span class="cTitle handle">%system</span><span class="removeMe">[x]</span></th>
            <th><span class="cTitle handle">%iowait</span><span class="removeMe">[x]</span></th>
            <th><span class="cTitle handle">%idle</span><span class="removeMe">[x]</span></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>12:10:01 AM</td>
            <td>28.86</td>
            <td>0.04</td>
            <td>1.65</td>
            <td>0.08</td>
            <td>69.36</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>12:20:01 AM</td>
            <td>26.54</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>1.64</td>
            <td>0.08</td>
            <td>71.74</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>12:30:01 AM</td>
            <td>29.73</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>1.66</td>
            <td>0.09</td>
            <td>68.52</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.removeMe {
  font-size: .65em;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -0.5em;
  color: #aaa;
}

.removeMe:hover {
  color: #222;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function removeColumn(n, o) {
  o = (o != "undefined") ? o : $("#testTable1");
  o.find("tr").each(function(k, e) {
    if (k == 0) {
      $(e).find("th").eq(n).hide("slow").remove();
    } else {
      $(e).find("td").eq(n).hide("slow").remove();;
    }
  });
  return true;
}

var dragOptions = {
  dragHandle: '.handle'
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.defaultTable').dragtable(dragOptions);

  $('#test1').click(function() {
    var head = $("<th>").html("<span class='cTitle handle'>New Column</span>");
    var rm = $("<span>", {
        class: "removeMe"
      })
      .html("[X]")
      .click(function() {
        removeColumn($(this).parent().index());
        $(this).remove();
      });
    rm.appendTo(head);
    head.appendTo("#testTable1 > thead > tr");

    $("#testTable1 > tbody > tr").each(function(key, el) {
      $(el).append('<td>New Cell</td>');
    });

    $('.defaultTable').removeData().dragtable(dragOptions);
  });

  $('.removeMe').on("click", function() {
    removeColumn($(this).parent().index());
    $('.defaultTable').removeData().dragtable(dragOptions);
  });
});
```